# How to append one child into two parents?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I inserted some company in form with AJAX and append response to select box.

Sometimes Response append to Select 1 and sometimes to Select 2 but not both.

```
## add_company my submit form for Insert Company##
## company my form for insert Company##

$("#add_company").on("click",function () {
  var first = 1;
  var active = false;
  $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    active = true;
  }).ajaxStop(function () {
    active = false;
  });

  if (!active) {
    var search = $("#company").serialize();
    var option = "";
    var option_text = "";
    if (search != "") {
      $.get("./json/company.php", search, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
          option = document.createElement("option");
          option_text = document.createTextNode(value.name);
          option.appendChild(option_text);
          option.setAttribute("value",value.id);

          ##companies is Select 1 company Warranty Select2##

          document.getElementById("companies").appendChild(option);
          document.getElementById("company_warranty").appendChild(option);
          if(value.id) {
            var msg = document.createTextNode("با موفقیت ثبت شد");
            document.getElementById("message-succ").appendChild(msg);
            $("#succes").show("slow");
          } else {
            var msg = document.createTextNode("متاسفانه ذخیره نشد!!!");
            document.getElementById("message-dan").appendChild(msg);
            $("#unsucces").show("slow");
          }
        })
      }, 'json');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: A node can only be in one place in the DOM. You'll need to make a copy of it if you want to append to two select boxes.

Comment: If a node could have two parents, which would `.parentNode` return?

Comment: it's work tnx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One child cannot have two parents, what you can do is

```
clone the child and append as a child to other elements
```